# I want to sort data in a slab wise format in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that contains chit amount, chit paid etc.. and I want to display the data according to chit amount range like I want chit paid and other details in the table according to chit amount range between 100 000 - 200 000 can any one help me?

I have a table contain data like.

```
amount  outs     paid

500000  0        121565
1000000 0        121565
500000  195372   121565
100000  0        121565
2000000 37500    121565
1000000 0        121565
200000  14516    121565
500000  0        121565
4000000 0        121565
150000  0        121565
500000  12112    121565
1000000 0        121565
300000  0        121565
```

I want to arrange them in  according to the amount range like

```
100000-200000 
200000-300000
above 300000
```

in order and others fields should calculated according to the range

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand a word you said (except "I want"). What is "chit amount"? Data you posted is poorly formatted and is unreadable. Contains *many* values I don't recognize and suspect is mostly irrelevant. If I had to guess, I'd say that you need to use ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I just edited the question @Littlefoot

Comment: Please provide a list of all desired ranges, the minimum/maximum amounts in the table, and an example of one of the calculations based on range.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to generate ranges is by using the Connect By LEVEL method. The code below generates ranges for numbers less than a million by steps of 100K and above a million by steps of 1M...

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    LEVEL "LVL", 
    CASE WHEN LEVEL > 10 THEN (LEVEL - 10) * 1000000 ELSE (LEVEL - 1) * 100000 END "RANGE_FROM",
    CASE 
        WHEN LEVEL = 15 THEN Null
        WHEN LEVEL > 10 THEN ((LEVEL - 9)* 1000000) - 1 ELSE (LEVEL * 100000) - 1 END "RANGE_TO",
    CASE
        WHEN LEVEL = 15 THEN To_Char((LEVEL - 10) * 1000000) || ' AND ABOVE' 
        WHEN LEVEL > 10 THEN To_Char((LEVEL - 10) * 1000000) || ' - ' || To_Char(((LEVEL - 9)* 1000000) - 1) ELSE To_Char((LEVEL - 1) * 100000) || ' - ' || To_Char((LEVEL * 100000) - 1) 
    END "WITHIN_RANGE"
FROM    dual
Connect By LEVEL <= 15
Order By LEVEL
/*   R e s u l t :
       LVL RANGE_FROM   RANGE_TO WITHIN_RANGE         
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
         1          0      99999 0 - 99999            
         2     100000     199999 100000 - 199999      
         3     200000     299999 200000 - 299999      
         4     300000     399999 300000 - 399999      
         5     400000     499999 400000 - 499999      
         6     500000     599999 500000 - 599999      
         7     600000     699999 600000 - 699999      
         8     700000     799999 700000 - 799999      
         9     800000     899999 800000 - 899999      
        10     900000     999999 900000 - 999999      
        11    1000000    1999999 1000000 - 1999999    
        12    2000000    2999999 2000000 - 2999999    
        13    3000000    3999999 3000000 - 3999999    
        14    4000000    4999999 4000000 - 4999999    
        15    5000000            5000000 AND ABOVE  
*/
```

With the data from your question...

```sql
WITH
    tbl (amount, outs, paid) AS
        (
            Select 500000,  0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 1000000, 0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 500000,  195372,   121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 100000,  0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 2000000, 37500,    121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 1000000, 0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 200000,  14516,    121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 500000,  0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 4000000, 0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 150000,  0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 500000,  12112,    121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 1000000, 0,        121565  From Dual Union All
            Select 300000,  0,        121565  From Dual 
        )
```

... you can choose the way to combine the data to get your desired result. I didn't get what it is, but here is one of the options resulting with rows from your data and a column defining the range that your AMOUNT belongs to.

```sql
Select 
    t.*, r.WITHIN_RANGE "WITHIN_RANGE"
From 
    ranges r
Inner Join
    tbl t ON(t.AMOUNT BETWEEN r.RANGE_FROM And r.RANGE_TO)

/*  R e s u l t :
    AMOUNT       OUTS       PAID WITHIN_RANGE        
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
    100000          0     121565 100000 - 199999     
    150000          0     121565 100000 - 199999     
    200000      14516     121565 200000 - 299999     
    300000          0     121565 300000 - 399999     
    500000          0     121565 500000 - 599999     
    500000     195372     121565 500000 - 599999     
    500000          0     121565 500000 - 599999     
    500000      12112     121565 500000 - 599999     
   1000000          0     121565 1000000 - 1999999   
   1000000          0     121565 1000000 - 1999999   
   1000000          0     121565 1000000 - 1999999   
   2000000      37500     121565 2000000 - 2999999   
   4000000          0     121565 4000000 - 4999999 
*/
```

You can order the resulting rows by any column(s) you want if that is what you are asking for. something like...

```sql
...
Order By r.RANGE_FROM
-- OR
Order By r.LVL DESC
-- OR
...
```

Regards...